# How delete inline-style with inlinecode html + class

Tags: html, jquery, css

How delete "width:400px" in my code:

```
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 400px;">
```

I dont have access inline-code :(
I must have other solved

Pleas, help.

Comment: You cannot change it it's comming from ```owl-carousel``` javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a more specific rule that overrides the inline style, e.g.

```
.owl-item.active {
  width: initial !important; /* or auto */
}
```

```css
.owl-item.active {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  width: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 400px;">div</div>
```

Note: that value is a result of some JS logic under the hood, so if you need to override that width it may be worth to check the settings of the carousel instance and the style applied.

Comment: is it good practice to overwrite default behaviour css? here from this ```owl-carousel``` CSS?

Comment: @Nikkkshit probably better to find a 3-party component that does what you (OP) actually want.